# simple $.click() returning Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.irq').click(function() {
    var set_irq = '<?php $_SESSION["page"] = "irq"; ?>';
});
```

Simple bit of code is returning Uncaught TypeError...

What could cause this?  No idea why console is giving this error.

Comment: Try outputting $ in the console...

Comment: There are a few possibilities, including: A version of `jquery.js` isn't being loaded in the page (as j08691 mentioned). It is loaded, but after this script tries to use it. `jQuery.noConflict()` is being used or `$` is otherwise being redefined so that it isn't an alias of `jQuery`.

Comment: Loaded jQuery right before it still getting the error.  Even tried to echo out the PHP except I want to set the session and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Hope there is error in this line

```
var set_irq = '<?php echo $_SESSION["page"] = "irq"; ?>';
```

You have to echo the content in php.

use double quotes outside and single quotes inside.